# How do I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{175}$ is not an additional subgroup of order $175$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Here was the original problem statement.

> Enumerate all non-isomorphic groups of order $175$.

See that $|G| = 175 = 5^2\cdot7$. Therefore by Sylow's first $H \leq G$ & $|H| = 25$ in addition to $K \leq G$ & $|K| = 7$. By Sylow's third $n_5 \equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $n | 7$, so $n_5 = 1$ and $H$ is normal. By Sylow's third $n_7 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and $n| 25$, so $n_7 = 1$ and $H$ is normal. So both $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups. We also know that $H \cap K = \{e\}$ because $\gcd(5, 7) = 1$.

Because $H \lhd G$ or $K \lhd G \Rightarrow HK \leq G$, therefore $HK \leq G$. $|HK| = 25 \cdot 7$ so $HK \cong G$. Because both groups are normal, $G \cong HK \cong H \times K$. Because $|H| = p^2 = 5^2$, therefore $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_7$.

But my proof is incomplete. I said that $G$ must be isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_7$... but it could be possible that all groups of order 175 are isomorphic to only $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ and never $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ . So I haven't shown that the group $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$  isn't an extraneous solution! How do I show that these groups are non-distinct?

Comment: I’m awfully sorry, but you seem to be saying that you think that $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_7$ may not be a group of order $175$.

Comment: @Lubin Let me explain. To prove "Find all objects of type X," you have to do two steps. (1) prove a series a disjunctions of the form O = A_1 \/ ... \/ O = A_n [this establishes that there are AT MOST n items] (2) Show that no two A_n's are equal to each other and that all A_n's actually exist [this establishes that there are AT LEAST n items]. The first half of the post only established (1). To finish proving the theorem, I needed to establish (2), which entails showing that Z_5 x Z_5 x Z_7, Z_25 x Z_7 exist as real groups (obvious, but needs to be stated) and are not equal. Clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . . . it could be possible that all groups of order $175$ are isomorphic to only $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ and never $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$. So I haven't shown that the group $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ isn't an extraneous solution! How do I show that these groups are non-distinct?

There are really two questions here:

1. Is $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ in fact isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$?
2. If not, can I find groups $G$ and $H$ such that $G \cong \Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ and $H \cong \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$?

The answer to the first question is no, they are not isomorphic. As @Mark points out in the comments below his answer, $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ has an element of order $25$, namely $(1,0)$, whereas there is no element of order $25$ in $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$. Hence, the two groups are non-isomorphic.

The answer to the second question is, yes: simply take $G$ to be $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ and $H$ to be $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$. That is, since every group is isomorphic to itself, we know that there is at least one group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ (namely, itself) and there is at least one group isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$, (namely, itself).

---

So, the map $\{ G : |G| = 175 \} \to \{ \Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7, \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7 \}$ which sends $G$ to its isomorphic copy in the codomain is a well-defined map into a two-element set that is also surjective:

- In your proof, you have shown that every group of order $175$ is isomorphic to either $\Bbb{Z}_{25} \times \Bbb{Z}_7$ or $\Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_5 \times \Bbb{Z}_7$. *(Well-definedness)*
- In the answer to question 1. you have shown that these are in fact distinct groups of order $175$. *(Codomain is a two-element set)*
- In the answer to question 2. you have shown that there is at least one group that is isomorphic to each of these groups. *(Surjectivity)*

Comment: You have posted the best answer so far kind sir. I have a question. In order to find an enumeration, does the map have to be surjective or bijective? It seems from your answer that an enumeration only requires that the map be surjective. Why?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Glad to be of help! Surjectivity suffices in this case: we want a minimal list of pairwise nonisomorphic groups of order 175 such that any other group of order 175 is isomorphic to one of the groups in our list. If the map is not surjective, then we have some extraneous groups which we can throw out of our list without any problem.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich There is no hope for bijectivity: for any group $G$, there are infinitely many groups that are isomorphic copies of $G$. For instance, $\Bbb{Z} / 2\Bbb{Z} = \{ \bar{0}, \bar{1} \} \cong \{ 0,a \} \cong \{ 0, b \} \cong \{ 0, c \} \cong \cdots$, where the group structure is defined in each case in the obvious manner. They are clearly isomorphic, and since the underlying sets are different, they are not the "same", but "only" isomorphic. So, bijectivity is too much to expect; what we want is surjectivity.

Answer (score 2):

You took a group of order $175$ (without making any other assumptions about the group) and you proved that it must be isomorphic to one of these two groups. So I don't really understand the question. $\mathbb{Z_{175}}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$, it follows from the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: This might be embarrassing, but I didn't think that I proved that any group of order 175 **must be** isomorphic to one of those two. I thought I only proved that those two groups are distinct groups of order 175 (but there could be more).

Comment: It happens. But yes, you took a group of order $175$ and you showed it is necessary isomorphic to one of the two groups. Hence there can't be any other groups of this order. (up to isomorphism of course)

Comment: I think I understand why my proof is incomplete. I said that $G$ must be isomorphic to either the first or the second... but it could be possible that all groups of order 175 are isomorphic to only the second and never the first. So I haven't shown that the first isn't an extraneous solution! How do I do that? I updated my answer.

Comment: This case is impossible because any group is isomorphic to itself. So $\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ has at least one group of order $175$ which is isomorphic to it-the group $\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ itself. Same thing about the second group.

Comment: I am talking about proof logic. If I showed that $G \cong X$ or $G \cong Y$, then I've only shown that these are there are **at maximum** two possible groups $G$ is isomorphic to. To turn this list into an enumeration, I need to show that there are **at minimum** two groups isomorphic to $G$ and that these two groups are not isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Any group $G$ is isomorphic only to one of these groups and can't be isomorphic to both. If your question is why these two groups are not isomorphic to each other then it is simple: the group $\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ has an element or order $25$ which is $(1,0)$. The group $\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ has no elements of such order.

Comment: It is true that any group $|G| = 175$ is isomorphic cannot be isomorphic to both. But how do I know that any group $|G| = 175$ is always isomorphic to one but never the other? "Or" statements are satisfied when only one of their arguments is true!

Comment: I really don't understand the problem. The two groups are not isomorphic so of course any group $G$ can be isomorphic only to one of them. As I said, if you take $G=\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ then of course it will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{25}}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$ so you don't have to worry about a case where all groups of order $175$ are isomorphic only to $\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_7}$. This case is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The group $H$ acts on $K = \mathbb{Z}_7$ by conjugation. Since $\#H = 25$ is prime to the order of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_7) = \mathbb{Z}_6$, that action must be trivial; that is, $H$ and $K$ commute, and $G = H \times K$. For $p$ prime, the only group of order $p$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the only groups of order $p^2$ are $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. (For the latter, note that any group of order $p^2$ has nontrivial center, and the only action of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ on itself is trivial by the same argument as for $K$ above.)